# Getting Posted Data from a Dynamic Form with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a page that contains a form, where part of it is dynamically generated based off of what SKU's are on an order.

```
<% for each i in ViewData.Model %>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $('#return_<%=i.SKUN%>').change(function () {
                                if ($('#return_<%=i.SKUN%>').val() > $('#qty_<%=i.SKUN%>').val()) {
                                    $('#Discrepancy').val("Yes");
                                } else {
                                    $('#Discrepancy').val("");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left"><%= i.SKUN%></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; width: 360px"><%= i.DESCR%></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&pound;<%= i.PRIC%></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left"><%= i.QUAN%></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&pound;<%= i.EXTP%></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left"><input type="hidden" name="qty_<%=i.SKUN%>" id="qty_<%=i.SKUN%>" value="<%= i.QUAN%>"/><input type="text" name="return_<%=i.SKUN%>" id="return_<%=i.SKUN%>" style="width:50px;" class="required"/>
                            <%  If i.FLAG3 = "T" Then
                                   %> <img src="../../Content/images/icons/error.png" alt="This SKU is subject to a <%=Html.ViewData("RestockFee") %>% restocking fee" title="This SKU is subject to a <%=Html.ViewData("RestockFee") %>% restocking fee"/><%
                                End If%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% Next%>
```

It's by no means perfect, but it gets the job done at the moment.

The part I'm struggling with is as `return_<%=i.SKUN%>` is a series of dynamically generated text boxes that change for each order, though they remain with the naming convention of `return_<%=i.SKUN%>`, how do I get the values for them in my controller that handles the form post?

**EDIT:** It's also important to note that none of these fields are required fields and that the number of text boxes varies per order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you change the naming convention to:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    name="skuns[<%= index %>]"
    id="return_<%= i.SKUN %>"
    style="width:50px;"
    class="required"
    value="<%= i.SKUN %>"
/>
```

where `index` would be an incrementing variable from 0 to n. This way your controller action could look like this:

```
Public Function Result(skuns As String()) As ActionResult
```

And leave the default model binder do the job.

Comment: If the default binder has difficulties, you could enumerate over Request.Form.Where(q=>q.Name.StartsWith("skuns["));

Comment: As long as you respect the naming convention the default model binder never has difficulties and using strongly typed action arguments is better.